# URLs contain double slash in path for all links within the 'X people chatting' container

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

I noticed the container that holds the 'X people chatting' content, `<div class="s-sidebarwidget mb16 module">` contains links that all have a double slash `//` in the URL after the authority where the path begins.

Each of the chat room categories like `HTML / CSS / WebDesign` links show the double slash in the HTML (ie when you hover your mouse over the link) it shows [chat.stackoverflow.com//rooms/29074](https://chat.stackoverflow.com//rooms/29074). After clicking the link and navigating to the chat room the URL is updated and the `//` goes away so its [chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign) like expected.

When hovering any of the users links they also show the `//` in the HTML but after clicking a link in the container, the `//` persists in the URL and we end up with [chat.stackoverflow.com//users/1140368](https://chat.stackoverflow.com//users/1140368). I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523318/is-a-url-with-in-the-path-section-valid) and the [RFC spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) that URLs with a `//` in the path after the authority are considered "valid" and servers might ignore it but browsers do not. I wasn't sure if this warranted a fix, but wanted to bring attention to it.